# How can I add to a predefined method?

Tags: c#, methods, overriding

I was wondering if there is a way to add to a predefined method such that everything that the method already does runs the same, but it just incorporates what I want it to do.

The method is from an outside dll and I want to just add something that adds the parameters to an arraylist every time that the method is called.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have any code? What happens when you run that code? We'll help with existing code, but we're not here to write it for you.

Comment: I really just don't know where to start with this. I want to record the parameters of a command in the PlayerIO dll, "Send". You start by establishing the connection: "Connection con", then I'll call the method with "con.Send("say", "text");" would in turn send out the string "text". What I'm hoping to do is record in some sort of array "say" and "text" every time I call "Send"

Comment: If you're asking to augment an _existing_ method's behaviour, you might be out of luck unless that method/class has been designed with extensibility in mind. If you have control over _all_ the source code calling that method, you can add a new method (say an extension method as gorrilla suggested) and call that instead, but if you don't have access to update all the pieces of code that call the original method, I don't think there's much you can do short of recompiling/modifying the DLL.

Comment: @Chris Yeah, I was afraid of that, but maybe I'll try getting the source and adding an extension method; that seems to be my best option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an extension class

```
    public static class ClassNameExtension
{
    // must have different signature to prevent memory exception
    public static string MethodToOverid(this ClassName class, List<T> tochange)
    {
        tochange.add(class)
        class.originalmethod()
    }
}
```

This is why when you bring in the namespace System.Linq objects suddenly get new methods

Comment: with extensions you don't need access to there dll just your code. create a class, if you put it in a namespace add the using and it will attach it's self to the correct objects.